# PHP: how to import from xml Array of links to images?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, xml, image

I want to extract images from array and transfer it to MySQL. Can someone add missing code down where it says WHAT TO PUT HERE.

Can someone help?
This is my code:

```
function __construct() {
    $this->client = new SoapClient($this->serverWsdlUrl);

    $this->db = new mysqli($this->sqlParams[0], $this->sqlParams[1], $this->sqlParams[2],
        $this->sqlParams[3], $this->sqlParams[4], $this->sqlParams[5]);

    if ($this->db->connect_errno) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $this->db->connect_error);
        exit();
    }
}
function fillProducts() {
    $response = $this->client->GetCTProducts_WithAttributes($this->clientParams);

    try {
        foreach ($response->GetCTProducts_WithAttributesResult->CTPRODUCT as $prod) {

          //$image = $prod->IMAGE_URLS->URL;
if (is_array($prod->IMAGE_URLS->URL)) {
        foreach ($prod->IMAGE_URLS->URL as $img) {

/**  <--- WHAT TO PUT HERE TO EXTRACT LINK IMAGES FROM ARRAY???

        }
```

}
    else
    {
            $image = $prod->IMAGE_URLS->URL;
    }

Comment: What is current output? Error/exception message? Very pertinent information to help. Plus, snippet of XML can help for reproducible example.

Comment: http://www.pcc.ba/shop2/detaljnoct.php?cat=PHD2511

Comment: current output is if one image it displays link to image.

Comment: but if many images (array) then in mysql field i got text: "array", so i made smth like this but i am missing smth here:
//$image = $prod->IMAGE_URLS->URL;
if (is_array($prod->IMAGE_URLS->URL)) {
            foreach ($prod->IMAGE_URLS->URL as $img) {
                        //...
            }
}
else
{
            $image = $prod->IMAGE_URLS->URL;
}

Comment: In updated code, `$img` (the loop variable) should be the string of image link. See with `echo $img;` in loop. Does it not return what you need?

Comment: It returns one image of array, i need all of it, and import it in mysql in field "images" and then echo four images.